# Using sequelize, what's the correct way to use a joined table's column value in a where clause?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize on a MySQL database. I am getting all records on one table while joining it with another table. I am trying to not include the result if a `WHERE` condition on the joined table is not met. In the `WHERE` clause I am trying to compare a value from the main table to the joined table and it's not working:

```
const expiredMemberships = await Membership.findAll({
include: [
  {
    model: User,
    attributes: ['id'],
    include: [
      {
        model: Post,
        required: true,
        attributes: ['id', 'created'],
        where: {
          created: {
            [Op.gt]: '$Membership.created$',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
],
attributes: ['id', 'created'],
where: {
  isActive: true,
},
```

});

It creates the following query:

```
SELECT `Membership`.`id`, 
       `Membership`.`created`, 
       `user`.`id` AS `user.id`, 
       `user->posts`.`id` AS `user.posts.id`, 
       `user->posts`.`created` AS `user.posts.created` 
  FROM `membership` AS `Membership` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `user` AS `user` INNER JOIN `post` AS `user->posts` 
       ON `user`.`id` = `user->posts`.`user_id` 
      AND `user->posts`.`created` > 'Invalid date' ) 
  ON `Membership`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` 
  AND (`user`.`deleted` = '9999-12-31 23:59:59') 
WHERE `Membership`.`is_active` = true;
```

You can see it is showing `'$Membership.created$'` as `Invalid date`. What's the correct way to use a joined table's column value in a where clause?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using aliasing for created field of membership table as **membership_created**

```
const expiredMemberships = await Membership.findAll({
   include: [
    {
      model: User,
      attributes: ['id'],
      include: [
         {
             model: Post,
             required: true,
             attributes: ['id', 'created'],
             where: {
             created: {
                [Op.gt]: 'membership_created',
              },
         },
     },
   ],
  },
],
attributes: ['id', ['created', 'membership_created']],
where: {
      isActive: true,
    },
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get `Invalid date`

Comment: can you provide me the query generated

Comment: `SELECT `Membership`.`id`, `Membership`.`created` AS `membership_created`, `user`.`id` AS `user.id`, `user->posts`.`id` AS `user.posts.id`, `user->posts`.`created` AS `user.posts.created` FROM `membership` AS `Membership` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `user` AS `user` INNER JOIN `post` AS `user->posts` ON `user`.`id` = `user->advances`.`user_id` AND `user->advances`.`created` > 'Invalid date' ) ON `Membership`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` AND (`user`.`deleted` = '9999-12-31 23:59:59') WHERE `Membership`.`is_active` = true;

Comment: can you please check the value of column created in membership table, does it contain a valid date ?

Comment: `2019-06-11 19:16:01`

Comment: why the query you have provided in comments and in the question's text are different and how the user->advances.user_id, came in query while we doesn't provided its association ?